# CSS Sub Menu on site is not functioning as expected

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

When I hover on menus the sub menu appears but disappears before it can be used, I've tried adding margins and z-index in various places but can't seem to find the exact problem.

www.stlymbnwyboutique.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Right now, this question is missing too much information for another user to help you.  Perhaps you could edit in images or longer descriptions of the problem so that we might better diagnose your issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generaly, it is not encouraged to provide links to external resources; instead you should provide MCVE code (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). On the other hand, my quick guess would be that there's a gap between the menu buttons and submenu dropdowns, so when you move the coursor, it leaves the "menu+submenu" area.

Comment: give to ul margin top -10px .top-bar ul>li.has-dropdown .dropdown { margin: -10px 0 0 0 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.top-bar ul>li.has-dropdown .dropdown{top:35px;}
```

Comment: Thank you jian dan and El.oz, both solutions work great